# Curl not working with PHP 5.4.6

Tags: php, lighttpd

I'm trying to use Curl to send and receive XML information from my credit card company and it works great in a shared server (sandbox). However, now that I uploaded it to my dedicated server it does not work.

Below is the Curl information from my *phpinfo* file:

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.19.7
Age  3
Features
AsynchDNS   No  
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   Yes
IDN         Yes
IPv6    Yes
Largefile   Yes
NTLM    Yes
SPNEGO  No
SSL     Yes
SSPI    No
krb4    No
libz    Yes
CharConv    No
Protocols   tftp, ftp, telnet, dict, ldap, ldaps, http, file, https, ftps
Host    i486-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version GnuTLS/2.8.5
ZLib Version    1.2.3.3
```

I'm using lighttpd, do I need to add something in its config file?

Comment: What happens when you execute curl command?

Comment: @MarceloSrougi If the question is resolved, please add it as an answer below and accept it when you can (alternatively you can delete the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved adding `curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);`